# How To Create Conditional From MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql

We used to process MySQL result with this method :

```
$sql = "SQL query here";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //--- do something for each row
    }
}
```

my question is, how can we create conditional inside `while` relates with `$result`, for example :

```
$sql = "SQL query here";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $client_name = $row['client_name'];
        //-- step 1 : count how many 'client_name' in $result
        //-- step 2 : IF more than 5, do something...

    }
}
```

my problem is, when I tried to `print_r($result)`, it only gives me :

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 15 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 11606 [type] => 0 )
```

while what I want to do is to perform 'search and count' with that `[num_rows] => 11606`. how can we do this?

Comment: If you want to get a count of a field, you should really add COUNT(field) to your query. Otherwise you will have to loop through the entire result set to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

try fetching the row as an array:

```
$sql = "SQL query here";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $client_name = $row['client_name'];
    //-- step 1 : count how many 'client_name' in $result
    //-- step 2 : IF more than 5, do something...

   }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, bro.. but it seems there's something wrong with :  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)), because I tried to `print_r($result)` after that, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: This is **exactly** the same code as OP posted, except you have changed an OO call (`$result->fetch_assoc`) into a procedural one (`mysql_fetch_array`) that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: bro I just get the php.net example https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
and you're printing result which is an object, so you need these function to fetch this object into rows,